# Fullcalendar 5; JSON feed from MVC Controller not working (.NET CORE 3)

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-core, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm implementing fullcalendar v5 in my .NET CORE 3 MVC project. When hard-coding events everything works fine,but I cannot seem to get events from a JSON string working. The calendar is triggering the method to get the feed, but no events are rendered. I tried about everything, read more than 100 webpages and issues here in stack overflow, but to no avail.

Method in my MVC controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public string GetAllEvents(DateTime Start, DateTime End)
{
   List<GetPromoCalendarEventsDto> calendarEvents = _promoCalendarAppService.GetAllEvents(Start, End).Result;
   var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(calendarEvents); 
   return result;
}
```

Content result:

```
[
{"title":"Event one","start":"2020-06-13","end":"2020-09-01"},
{"title":"Event two","start":"2020-06-14","end":"2020-12-30"},
{"title":"Test 20200623.001Y","start":"2020-07-03","end":"2020-08-03"}
]
```

Javascript:

```
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('promocalendar');
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
    events: 'PromoCalendar/GetAllEvents'
});
calendar.render();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look in your browser's Developer Tools - watch the Network tool when the page loads. Do you see an entry for "GetAllEvents"? Does it return an 200 OK result? If so, then what exactly is the content in the Response (you'd have to click on the entry to display this extra info)? Does it display what you expected? Also, are there any errors shown in the Console area? This is basic debugging of your client-side code which you need to do when dealing with problems of this nature.

Comment: In theory, what you've shown as the cotent result should be valid to display in fullCalendar. If it isn't displaying, then you need to double-check what's really going on, using the tools I've mentioned above.

Comment: @ADyson: I see an entry for "GetAllEvents" with an 200 OK result and the following response:

`error: null
result: "[{"title":"Event one","start":"2020-06-13","end":"2020-09-01"},{"title":"Event two","start":"2020-06-14","end":"2020-12-30"},{"title":"Test 20200623.001Y","start":"2020-07-03","end":"2020-08-03"}]"
success: true
targetUrl: null
unAuthorizedRequest: false`

Comment: You must return the event array in your JSON alone, nothing else can be in there. fullCalendar expects just to see the array. It does not know to look inside the "results" property of that JSON to find the info it needs. Just return a pure array without an object around it.

Comment: When I look at the pure response I see:

`{"result":"[{\"title\":\"Event one\",\"start\":\"2020-06-13\",\"end\":\"2020-09-01\"},{\"title\":\"Event two\",\"start\":\"2020-06-14\",\"end\":\"2020-12-30\"},{\"title\":\"Test 20200623.001Y\",\"start\":\"2020-07-03\",\"end\":\"2020-08-03\"}]","targetUrl":null,"success":true,"error":null,"unAuthorizedRequest":false,"__abp":true}`, so that is wrong in a lot of ways, I guess. The framework I use, adds a lot of information I see..

Comment: That appears to be some double-encoding. Not sure what caused that. Is that you looking at it in the Visual Studio debugger or something? But the more important thing is that your DTO object has the wrong structure, as I mentioned above . You need to just return a list of events

Comment: Thank you, you put me on the right path. The framework I use wrapped the result with other data. I added the tag `[DontWrapResult]` and everything works fine now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! I have put [DontWrapResult] above the method and it worked. The framework I use (ABP) wraps the result with other data and double-encodes the JSON string.

Thanks to @ADyson for putting me on the right path!